# Is it possible to Disable "Open In..." for a generated PDF in iOS preview

Tags: ios, uikit, pdf-generation, qlpreviewcontroller

I have an iOS app I'm writing for the iPad/iPhone.  I'm generating a PDF report for printing, and have everything working, where the app will successfully open the generated PDF in QLPreviewController, I am using the following code to open the preview:

```
// open a preview of the PDF File. 
    QLPreviewController* preview = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
    preview.dataSource = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:preview animated:YES];
```

After the PDF is opened in Preview, you have the standard buttons on the Preview toolbar. The buttons are "Done" and an "Action Button" for printing/opening the pdf in other apps.

I included a screenshot of what I'm talking about.

[image]

My question is, is there a quick way to disable/disallow the "Open in 'iBooks'" and "Open In..." options?  I want to only allow the user to print the pdf.  I know I can send the pdf directly to print without opening preview, but I want to allow the user to preview the pdf prior to printing.  So really, I just need to disable the "open in" options.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done.  You need to create a subclass of `QLPreviewController` and assign your own button to `self.rightBarButtonItem` in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`.  In addition, your class should listen for `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` and do the same thing in the callback method(s) for those notifications.

You can replicate the print button functionality with [`UIPrintInteractionController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).